# Extract a part of a changeabel string

Tags: r

I have a simple but yet complicated question (at least for me)!

I would like to extract a part of a string like in this example:

From this string:

```
name <- "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test/plots/"
```

To this:

```
name <- "test/plots/"
```

The plot twist for my problem that the names are changing. So its not always "test/plots/", it could be "abc/ccc/" or "m.project/plots/" and so on.

In my imagination I would use something to find the last two "/" in the string and cut out the text parts. But I have no idea how to do it!

Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Without regex

Use `str_split` to split your path by `/`. Then extract the first three elements after reversing the string, and `paste` back the `/` using the `collapse` argument.

```
library(stringr)

name <- "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/m.project/plots/"

paste0(rev(rev(str_split(name, "\\/", simplify = T))[1:3]), collapse = "/")

[1] "m.project/plots/"
```

#### With regex

Since your path could contain character/numbers/symbols,  `[^/]+/[^/]+/$` might be better, which matches anything that is not `/`.

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(name, "[^/]+/[^/]+/$")

[1] "m.project/plots/"
```

Answer (score 2):

With {stringr}, assuming the path comprises folders with lower case letters only. You could adjust the alternatives in the square brackets as required for example if directory names include a mix of upper and lower case letters use `[.A-z]`
Check a regex reference for options:

```r
name <- c("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/m.project/plots/",
          "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test/plots/")

library(stringr)
str_extract(name, "[.a-z]+/[.a-z]+/$")
#> [1] "m.project/plots/" "test/plots/"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: it will not match `m.project/plots/`

Comment: @benson23: True. Opps sorry I missed that requirement in the question. Have adjusted the answer. Thanks for pointing this out.